# How to only extract match strings from a multi-value field and display in new column in SPLUNK Query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk, splunk-formula

i am trying to extract matched strings from the multivalue field and display in another column. I have tried various options to split the field by delimiter and then mvexpand and then user where/search to pull those data. I was trying to find if there is an easier way to do this without all this hassle in SPLUNK query.

**Example:** Lets say i have below multi-value column1 field with data separated by delimiter comma

> **column1** = abc1,test1,test2,abctest1,mail,send,mail2,sendtest2,new,code,results

I was splitting this column using delimiter `|eval column2=split(column1,",")` and using regex/where/search to search for data with `*test*` in this column and return results, where i was able to pull the results but the column1 still shows all the values `abc1,test1,test2,abctest1,mail,send,mail2,sendtest2,new,code,results` , what i want is either to trim1 **column1** to show only words match with `test` or show those entries in new **column2** which should only show this words `test1,test2,abctest1,sendtest2` as they were only matching `*test*`.

I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after posting this question, its just using exiting mvfilter function to pull the match resutls.

> column2=mvfilter(match(column1,"test"))

Answer (score 0):

```
| eval column2=split(column1,",") | search column2="*test*"
```

doesn't work, as the `split` creates a multi-value field, which is a single event containing a single field containing many values. The `search` for `*test*` will still find that event, even though it contains `abc1`, etc... as there is at least one field that is `*test*`.

What you can use is the `mvfilter` command to narrow down the multi-value field to the events you are after.

```
| eval column2=split(column1,",") | eval column2=mvfilter(match(column2,".*test.*"))
```

Alternatively to this approach, you can use a regular expression to extract what you need.

```
| rex field=column1 max_match=0 "(<?column2>[^,]*test[^,]*)"
```

Regardless, at the end, you would need to use `mvjoin` to join your multiple values into a single string

```
| eval column2=mvjoin(column2, ",")
```